# Short captions in \listoffigures when using \captionof

Tags: table-of-contents, captions

The question is fairly simple.

When using a `figure` environment I can use `\caption[Short version for LoF]{Long version to appear next to the figure}` to get a smaller caption in the \litoffigures.

Is there a way to do the same when using the `caption` package and `\captionof` for captions when figures are not in a `figure` environment?

Comment: Have you tried `\captionof{figure}[short]{long}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Campa answered my question:

```
\captionof{figure}[short]{long}
```

is how I get it done. Thanks!